# Room Database Migration with new column using unique values

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, android-room, database-migration

I am trying to add a new column to my room database's table for INDEX ! How can i use MIGRATION to alter the table in such a way that i get all the previous data into the table along with new unique indexes for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are new values and unique then you will have to generate the values.

The migration would be along the lines of:-

1. Rename the original table.
2. Create the table using the modified schema.
3. Create the index(s) using the modified schema.
4. extract the data from the renamed original table, applying the unique value and  inserting the data into the new table.
5. this may or may not be able to be undertaken in a single query.
6. it may need for the data to be extracted into a Cursor, perhaps a MatrixCursor could be beneficial.

- Note to get the correct SQL for creating the table(s) indexes then get the SQL from the generated java after compiling with the modifications. The generated java is plainly visible if you use Android View. The appropriate class is one that has the same name as the @Database class suffixed with **_Impl**. The SQL can be found in the **createAllTables** method.